# wcf service long time transition server client

Tags: wcf, iis, proxy, net.tcp

I have a `WCF service` in my application.
When the amount of data that passes from server to client is small I do not have problems.

The problems come when there's a big amount of data.

The proxy method runs a `stored procedure` that retrives data in an acceptable time.
The method server side return correctly,

**BUT it takes more that two minutes to return properly to the client and continue the execution client side.**

During this period if I stop the application it seems that no actions are in execution.

**I don't know if it's an IIS problem or a configuration of the net.tcp binding.**

The only thing I'm able to do is to execute the proxy in an external application and it that case I no have problems.

---

---

EDIT***

This is the binding configuration:

```
<binding name="NetTcpBinding_INService" closeTimeout="24.00:00:00" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
          openTimeout="24.00:00:00" receiveTimeout="24.00:00:00" sendTimeout="24.00:00:00">
          <security mode="None" />
        </binding>
```

Comment: what is your client and server binding configuration , please provide them.

Comment: @Aria I added the configuration

Comment: I think the time is spent in the query process, not in the WCF. I try using your binding configuration and found that there was no problem with returning string. I suggest that you review the process of querying data, for example, using windows integration authentication for connecting database.

Comment: @Galma88, Is your problem resolved?, There is no defined message size in your config, you know the default message size is 64K, but you can increase the message size if you need to use streamed mode and transfer large chunks of data. Anyway 2 minutes is not good at all.